# How do you access a pointer to a structure declared in another structure?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

My code is some what like this:

```
struct a{
           ....
           ....
           };
    struct a c[MAXNODES];

    struct b{
           int k;
           struct a *p;
           };
    struct b d[MAXNODES];
```

So,if i need to access the pointer to `struct a` in `struct b`should i use the indirection operator or not.

```
some_variable=*(d.[i-1].p);
```

Comment: This is not clear.  Why can't you do `d[idx].p`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 structures, where one holds the pointer to an instance of the other:

```
typedef struct a {
    int i;
} A;

typedef struct b {
    A *pA;
} B;
```

Then somewhere, you have an array of your structures, where instances of `struct a` reside:

```
A arr[10];

B b;
b.pA = &arr[0]; // makes b.pA to point to the address of first element of arr
b.pA->i = 2;    // equivalent to (*b.pA).i = 2;

A a = *b.pA;    // creates a copy of an element that b.pA points to
A* pA = b.pA;   // stores the reference (copies the pointer)
```